# Better way to doing with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I converted the following code into java 8 code. I would like to know if i did it properly or there is some other nice way.

Java 7

```
for (final Category category : categories) {
      final List<Category> subCategories = getCategories(category);
      if (subCategories != null) {
        currentLevel.addAll(subCategories);
      }
    }
```

Java8

```
categories.stream().map(category -> getCategories(category)).filter(list->list!=null).flatMap(cat -> cat.parallelStream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Any java 8 way to solve the following code into a compact form.

```
while (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(currentLevel)) {
  for (final Iterator<Category> iterator = currentLevel.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    final Category category = iterator.next();
    if (result == null) {
      result = new HashSet<Category>();
    }
    if (!result.add(category)) {
      // avoid cycles by removing all which are already found
      iterator.remove();
    }
  }

  if (currentLevel.isEmpty()) {
    break;
  }
  final Collection<Category> nextLevel = getAllSubcategories(currentLevel);
  currentLevel = nextLevel;
}
```

Comment: For me it looks quite good.

Comment: Updated ...i missed one clause in the beginning .flatMap(cat -> cat.parallelStream())

Comment: Are you just trying to end up with unique categories?  If so you might just use @stholzm's solution but use `Collectors.toSet()`.  Or, if you need a list, add a `.distinct()` step after the `flatMap`

Comment: Do you really need a 3rd party library for invoking `currentLevel.isEmpty()`?

Comment: @Holger Apache Commons `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty` and related methods are "null-safe" in that a null collection is considered empty. Not my preference, but a lot of people like this style.

Comment: @Stuart Marks: I know that they are “null safe” and that’s what makes them even more questionable. More than often, the developer never thought about the possibility of a reference being `null`, but emphasizes the null-safety only *after* being asked, to excuse the unnecessary use of a 3rd party library function. If developers really suspect a reference being potentially `null`, they should add an explicit test (I call `Objects.isNull` or `Objects.requireNonNull` explicit, in contrast to `isNotEmpty`), to document that assumption. Otherwise, “null safe” operations are the *source* of bugs.

Comment: @Holger In addition, a possibility is that some devs *don't know* whether the ref is nullable so they use the Common API "just in case" ... which propagates null-uncertainty elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is ok except the fact that flat-mapping to parallel stream is useless. If you take a look into [`flatMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#l267) implementation in OpenJDK/OracleJDK, you can see that the stream created via lambda passed into `flatMap` is immediately turned into sequential mode. So you will not have any parallelism and it's better to replace `parallelStream()` with `stream()` to avoid confusion. If you really want to parallelize the work, it's usually good idea to parallelize the outermost stream only.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a matter of preference, but you could replace those lambdas with method references:

```
categories.stream()
          .map(this::getCategories)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .flatMap(List::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Too bad the lists can be `null` apparently (really?)... otherwise you could just use `flatMap`.

And I wouldn't use `parallelStream` in another stream operation.

Comment: Looks very elegant. +1 . I will try to remove the null condition. How can i do with iterator like i updated.

Comment: If you're using an `Iterator`, it's not going to be much better.  Why do you want to do it with an iterator?  That's like asking "how can I build a sand castle with this pair of tweezers."  You can do it, but it's going to be longer and harder than using the right tools for the job.

Comment: @LouisWasserman : Oh iterator was the second question i was referring to. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It doesn't look like that's possible to do with streams.  You can't e.g. do anything like the `iterator.remove()` with streams.

Answer (score 2):

For the second question, the usual streams-based approach to removing duplicates is to copy the elements into a different collection, processing them using the `distinct()` operation:

```
    Collection<Category> currentCopy = currentLevel.stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(toList());
```

But it seems that you're trying to manipulate the collection in-place instead of making a copy. To do this, you could do something like the following:

```
    Set<Category> result = new HashSet<>();
    currentLevel.removeIf(cat -> !result.add(cat));
```

Note that this isn't a streams operation, so you can't run it in parallel. You can't get much parallelism anyway, since the predicate has side effects.

Comment: What do you mean by *"since the predicate has side effects"* ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard A pure function produces its result only by reading values from its input and performing computations on those values. An impure function, or one with side effects, does things other than computing a result from its input. In my example the predicate `cat -> !result.add(cat)` mutates `result`. That's a side effect. If this were converted to a parallel stream, then multiple threads would be mutating `result` simultaneously, which would lead to corruption since `HashSet` isn't thread safe. That in turn would require synchronization or use of `ConcurrentHashMap`.